# Sent notification FCM before topic was created or before subscription

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Scenario: Send notification to topic "X" with expire time 4 weeks.
What happens when:

1. Topic does not exist, no one subscribed to it. Then after one hour,
   someone subscribe to it. Will this device get this notification?
2. Topic exists or existed (had one subscriber but he unscusribed), now he is subscribing again after an hour of sending. Will it get it?
3. One or more devices are subscribing to topic X. All of them got it. One new device now subscribe to it, after as always, an hour from sending. Will it get it?

Something is telling me "No" to all of those answers, but have problem with finding that answer in fcm documenation.

If I guessed right, what would be solution to get this previous notifications? Let's say for business it is important, and notification lives only for an hour, but in between he could change subscription and after getting back, he would like to get that notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCM Topics are auto-created when you send a message to it, or when somebody subscribes to them.

The device only receives messages that were sent to the topic after it subscribes. It does not receive messages that were sent to the topic when it isn't subscribed.

Since in all three questions the message is sent to the topic when the device isn't subscribed, it will not receive those messages.

For this type of scenario you'll want to use a persistent database, instead of a transient message passing mechanism. E.g. you can store the messages for each topic in a database, and grant the device access to that database when it subscribes to the topic.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Makes perfectly sense ;) But was not sure. Thanks for answer!